# node js - Is it need to close the connection when mysql task done?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to learn mysql npm on my Node js server.
I care about my server need to close connection from mysql when it done a task or not ?

This is my code

```
let insertUserByEmail = function (data, callback){
  db.query("INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (?,?)",[data.email, data.password], callback);
  // then close it
}
```

and the next task, i will connect again.

Is this my solution is good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to standard practice and security measures you should have to close any open database connection if made by your script. If you are leaving connection open then it will be auto time out by database server.

Specifically for node applications you can close connection after pool by

```
db.end(function (err) {
   // all open connections in the db cluster have ended
});
```